# присвоение значения input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть форма. На ней есть скрытые поля. значения этих полей должны передаться с формы. например:

```
<a href="#" id="show_inform">Доп.Информ.</a>
<div id="adress" style="display:none;"> пл. Толстого Льва </div>
<input type="hidden" name="adr">
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var a=$("#adress").text();

    $("#show_inform").click(function () {         
        if ($("#adress").is(":hidden"))
                {
                    $("#adress").show();
                    $('.adr').val(a);
                }
            });
    });
```

Я хочу в `input type="hidden" name="adr"` передать текст "пл. Льва Толстого",    если пользователь кликает по ссылке. Но с формы в этом инпуте ничего не передается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в скрытый input идентификатор и работайте с ним:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var a=$("#adress").text();

    $("#show_inform").click(function () {         
        if ($("#adress").is(":hidden"))
                {
                    $("#adress").show();
                    $('#adress-hidden').val(a);
                }
            });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="show_inform">Доп.Информ.</a>
<div id="adress" style="display:none;"> пл. Толстого Льва </div>
<input id="adress-hidden" type="hidden" name="adr">
```

или вместо

```
$('.adr').val(a);
```

используйте

```
$('input[name="adr"]').val(a);
```

Comment: Ой. ну, конечно! я же неправильно пишу. adr это же не класс. а я пишу $('.adr').val(a); Спасибо за подсказку!